# Javascript: Get milliseconds of today at midnight

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like to calculate what the timestamp is of today at midnight, but in milliseconds.

I currently have:

```
  var d = new Date();
  d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

And this outputs:

```
Thu Mar 20 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

How can I convert this into a timestamp based on milliseconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(+d);
```

Comment: Wow, this works beautifully. I tried to use console.log(d) and it returned the output in my question. What does the + sign do the output?

Comment: The + sign tries to convert the operand to its integer equivalent. It works on most types. (e.g. +'8' will give you the number 8)

Comment: Learn something new every day :) Thanks!